# Could 'going' mean 'saying'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am trying to understand what my professor said, especially what 'going' means in the following sentence. Did she actually say like that or just think to herself?

> At the conference, I was sitting there **going** ‘what is your definition of *****?’

Answer (score 1):

Either is possible, in context I think it is unlikely that she was actually speaking out loud.

Wiktionary has the sense of "go" as "speak or make a sound" ([sense 28](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go#Verb))

The continuous form "was going" suggests that this wasn't a single action, but either repeated or continued over some time.  That seems unlikely for actual speech in a conference while somebody else is presenting.  So I'd understand this as a question that she is thinking about, she is repeatedly thinking the question, but not actually calling it out.

Comment: Yes, she said she was like that for 5 years at conferences. Thank you.